# GraphQL query commit history in range on 2 commits

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I am trying to get list of all commits between 2 given cursors.

I have tried to use before and after argument for history

```
ref(qualifiedName: $branch) {
   target {
     ... on Commit {
        history(after:$firstCommit, before: $lastCommit) {
          totalCount
```

I want it to return just commits between these 2 tags, but it returns whole list.

Comment: This actually seems like a bug on the GitHub for the history, the `before` and `after` do not work together in this specific case.